# How to Access Apache Ignite Service Grid services from j2ee aplication or from outside the Ignite cluster

Tags: service, ignite

I want to access  services running on Apache Ignite cluster from a J2ee application running on wildfly10 application server. is there an option to achieve this integration? 
How do we expose Apache Ignite service grid services to outside world outside the Ignite cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create Singleton session bean(as it is never passivated) with Ignite client in it. With client node you will connect to Ignite cluster. Here is [documentation about clients and servers](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers).

Comment: I implemented this approach however if the system remains idel for a while the client-node is somehow sending a shutdown/interupt to the j2ee server and the entire server is shutting down post that. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by " client-node is somehow sending a shutdown/interupt to the j2ee server"? Sorry, Didn't get it